# Creating a drop down menu under navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar and I want it to have a drop down menu. I have searched online on other sites including this forum but none of it have worked for me so far as it screwed up the styling of the navigation bar instead. So I hope to find another possible solution by asking here.

This is how i want the navigation bar to look like when hovering over it with a drop down menu. 
[dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Gx1.png)

These are my html codes and css codes.

HTML Codes:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="main"><a href="cart.php" target="_blank"><img style ="margin-top:-5px;"  src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2u43au0.png" border="0" width="25" height="25"/></a></li>
    <li class="main"><a href="#about">About</a></li> 
    <li class="main"><a href="login.php">Login/Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS Codes:

```
ul.main {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -10px -30px;
    width: 1268px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

li.main {
    float: right;
}

li.main a {
    display:  block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
   font-family:Helvetica;
   font-size:13px;
    height: 50px;
}

li.main a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vds0LLg9/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very helpful website that will teach you how to make dropdown menus.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

I would highly recommend any of their tutorials.